# Jenkins HPE Automation Tool Plugin timeout issues

Tags: jenkins, hp-uft

I use HPE Automation Tool plugin in Jenkins to run UFT(CI/CD). In the configuration I have put a timeout of 36000 sec(10 hours). Ideally UFT should terminate after 10 hours but it is not terminating and keeps on running.

At the same time if I change the timeout configuration to 2 minutes it works like a charm. But the project that I am working on needs that 10 hours timeout configuration.

[image: This is how I have set the configuration]

UFT version 14.03 is installed in a windows server and the scripts run there.
HPE Automation Tool Plugin version used is 5.2.

Can someone please provide me their inputs, what may the issue?

Comment: I don't think you can wait that long if you go to the WIKI page https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HPE+Application+Automation+Tools ... someone talks about the connection getting disconnected after 30 mins... Also Have you confirmed that the job is still running during  entire 10 hours  !!!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin uses the QuickTest.Application COM Object to start and control the Test Robot(UFT). I had many issues with UFT running more than 2 hours without any restart (I had my own script driving it) - so I wouldn't assume it is an issue of the Plug-in but of UFT. You could try investigate it further but hey let me tell you my tests:

1. Have some long tests and run them directly from UFT (Do they run for 10 hours without restart? - mine didn't)
2. Do the same but drive the execution via a script.

If all those 2 is OK, well then you can assume it is the Plug-in, but again my personal experience with the 2 ways mentioned above led me to the conclusion that it is UFT and not the driver scripts.

What I can propose as an alternative:

Have milestones (Save some Item IDs, critical data somewhere (DB, Files) - restart UFT regularly and reload data stored in the milestone